# Usefulness of an MS extensions to C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The last item in [Microsoft extensions to C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8.aspx), "Passing a Non-Const Pointer Parameter to a Function that Expects a Reference to a Const Pointer Parameter", is an extension and hence it could be considered a *beneficial* feature. However, I fail to see its value. The very example they show suggests it is dangerous.

```
typedef int T;

const T  acT = 9;                 // A constant of type 'T'
const T * pcT = & acT;            // A pointer to a constant of type 'T'

void func2 ( const T * & rpcT )   // A reference to a pointer to a constant of type 'T'
{
    rpcT = pcT;
}

T * pT;                           // A pointer to a 'T'

void func ()
{
    func2 ( pT );                 // Should be an error, but isn't detected
    * pT   = 7;                   // Invalidly overwrites the constant 'acT'
}
```

Why is it an extension and not a bug?

Comment: Because it is Microsoft, and they like to add arbitrary operations that won't compile on standard compilers so that you have to develop code for just their OS. Disclaimer: This answer is biased by the fact I dislike Microsoft. For a more serious response, that is extremely strange and not sure why they would specifically allow it. They probably have a reason somewhere in the documentation for it.

Comment: Presumably because there is enough legacy code that relies on this 'bug' (probably unintentionally) that they're unwilling to remove the extension.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend_and_extinguish): “"**Embrace, extend, and extinguish**", also known as "**Embrace, extend, and exterminate**", is a phrase that the U.S. Department of Justice found that was used internally by Microsoft to describe its strategy for entering product categories involving widely used standards, extending those standards with proprietary capabilities, and then using those differences to disadvantage its competitors”. And I highly suspect that the culture that produced EEE, and also a Wikipedia MS litigation page, is very relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "It's not a bug, it's a feature."

Yes, this is clearly a bad thing. You'd have to ask the Microsoft engineers responsible, but I suspect it was a bug and it was maintained only because at some point somebody's software depended on it and Microsoft wanted to maintain backwards compatibility.

However, it appears that this documentation is out of date: I can't get Visual Studio 2015 or 2013 to accept code using this extension.

Comment: Interesting, the example does not compile indeed.